# Iniciando con el framework Spring, Como solucionar 2 Errores que me da Spring tool Suite v3.9.7 Release?

Tags: spring

Hola a todos un gusto saludarles, verán, quise empezar aprender Spring, estoy usando Sring Tool Suite v3.9.7 Release, intente hacer un clásico hola mundo pero me da 2 errores y 2 warnings. Sabe alguien como poder solucionarlos?, gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Las dependencias del proyecto se manejan con Maven?

Comment: Si, el proyecto lo hice con maven. Gracias por contestarme